# Bootstrap datetimepicker initial value

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm having a slight issue with Bootstrap's DateTimePicker. The issue I'm having is when the picker is first loaded it appears to be getting the value from a hidden input element instead of the value from the input box that it is attached to.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
$('.the_date').datetimepicker({
    format: 'd MM yyyy',
    linkFormat: 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:ii:ssZ',
    weekStart: 1,
    language: 'en',
    todayBtn:  0,
    autoclose: 1,
    todayHighlight: 1,
    startView: 2,
    minView: 2,
    forceParse: 0,
    pickerPosition: "bottom-left"
});

<div class="item-date the_date date" data-date-startdate="22/08/14" data-link-field="OrderItem_0_preferredDate">
        <input type="text" class="datepicker form-control" placeholder="Date" data-link-field="OrderItem_0_preferredDate" value="22/08/14">

        <input name="OrderItem[0][preferredDate]" id="OrderItem_0_preferredDate" type="hidden" value="2014-08-21T22:00:00Z">        
 </div>
```

The value that is being shown by default in the picker is 21 August 2014 (21/08/14) which is incorrect.

I want the startdate to be the value from the "data-date-startdate" attribute.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
<div id="start-date" class="item-date the_date date" data-date-startdate="22/08/14" data-link-field="OrderItem_0_preferredDate">
    <input type="text" class="datepicker form-control" placeholder="Date" data-link-field="OrderItem_0_preferredDate" value="22/08/14">

    <input name="OrderItem[0][preferredDate]" id="OrderItem_0_preferredDate" type="hidden" value="2014-08-21T22:00:00Z">        
</div>

$('.the_date').datetimepicker({
    ...
    defaultDate:$('#start-date').attr('data-date-startdate')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Jsut try this:
        $(.the_date').datetimepicker({
        language:  'fr',
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn:  1,
        autoclose: 1,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 1,
        minView: 0,
        maxView: 1,
        forceParse: 0,
        showMeridian: 1,
        startDate: '2018-9-7 '12:00:00',

      });
```

Comment: A good answer has a better explanation [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)